# How to provide subscriber with routing capability

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have following path for stream -

```
 kafkaStream[message] -> 
 kafkaStream[message] -> mergedKafkaStream[message] -> stream[EnrichedMessage] -> I/O
 kafkaStream[message] ->
```

I am not sure how to write this in akka stream way.
I tried following (pseudo).

```
KafkaStream extends ActorPublisher[message] {

}

IOHandler extends ActorSubscriber {

}
```

k1, k2, k3 are kafka streams publishers

```
f = Flow[message].map(_.enrichMessage)

FlowGraph { b =>
  k1 ~> merge
  k2 ~> merge
  k3 ~> merge
  merge ~> f ~> ioHandlerSink
}
```

So this is the way I connect publisher to sink. But here the problem that I want to resolve is slow IO. IOHandler actor is very slow for processing message, so how I can have multiple IOHandlers and I should be able to distribute the tasks. And I also want to maintain the back pressure so not using fire and forget using router.

I am very new to akka stream, so suggest me a way out.

Thanks

Comment: akka-streams itself is new so functionality may still be missing :) In particular there's [ticket #15959](https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/15959) that suggest something that might be similar to what you are looking for. It isn't yet implemented but if you add a comment about what you would expect it to do that could be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can route to multiple `IOHandler` sinks using a [`Balance`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M3/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Balance) junction in your `FlowGraph`.